# Fatal error: Call to undefined method wSpider::fetchPage()

Tags: php, curl

The error is :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method wSpider::fetchPage()
```

Firstly, what I'm trying to do is build a spider to get data from a webpage. I'm not exactly sure why I'm getting this error, but I'm fairly new to php so it could be something fairly obvious that I'm missing. Code:

```
<?php
class wSpider
{
var $ch; /// going to used to hold our cURL instance
var $html; /// used to hold resultant html data
var $binary; /// used for binary transfers
var $url; /// used to hold the url to be downloaded

function wSpider()
{
$this->html = "";
$this->binary = 0;
$this->url = “”;
}
}

function fetchPage($url)
{
$this->url = $url;
if (isset($this->url)) {
$this->ch = curl_init (); /// open a cURL instance
curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // tell cURL to return the data
curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); /// set the URL to download
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); /// Follow any redirects
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $this->binary); /// tells cURL if the data is binary data or not
$this->html = curl_exec($this->ch); // pulls the webpage from the internet
curl_close ($this->ch); /// closes the connection
}
}

$mySpider = new wSpider(); //// creates a new instance of the wSpider
$mySpider->fetchPage("http://www.msn.com"); /// fetches the home page of msn.com
echo $mySpider->html; /// prints out the html to the screen

?>
```

The specific line in question is

```
$mySpider->fetchPage("http://www.msn.com"); /// fetches the home page of msn.com
```

I'd be very grateful for any help to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fetchPage method in your class, that's why it isn't working. That's why you should indent your code.  Try

```
<?php
class wSpider
{
    var $ch; /// going to used to hold our cURL instance
    var $html; /// used to hold resultant html data
    var $binary; /// used for binary transfers
    var $url; /// used to hold the url to be downloaded

    function wSpider()
    {
        $this->html   = "";
        $this->binary = 0;
        $this->url    = “”;
    }
    function fetchPage($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        if (isset($this->url)) {
            $this->ch = curl_init(); /// open a cURL instance
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // tell cURL to return the data
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); /// set the URL to download
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); /// Follow any redirects
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $this->binary); /// tells cURL if the data is binary data or not
            $this->html = curl_exec($this->ch); // pulls the webpage from the internet
            curl_close($this->ch); /// closes the connection
        }
    }
}


$mySpider = new wSpider(); //// creates a new instance of the wSpider
$mySpider->fetchPage("http://www.msn.com"); /// fetches the home page of msn.com
echo $mySpider->html; /// prints out the html to the screen

?>
```

Your class ends right here

```
$this->url = “”;
}
} // right here
```

and function is defined AFTER that bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You 've got a brace issue that causes `fetchPage` to not be a member of your class:

```
function wSpider()
{
$this->html = "";
$this->binary = 0;
$this->url = “”;
}
} // This brace ends your class declaration! Move it!
```

You might also want to rename the constructor to `__construct`, as is recommended.

Comment: NO that would make a bracket mismatch... OP needs to move the fetch page function into his class

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: I think even a total newbie would realize that.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke: Should be OK now, but there's really nothing gained from being pedantic here.